# For which purpose are those resistors on the ANT output?

Tags: frequency-modulation

I've bought a cheap FM transmitter and installed it in my car, but sadly, it gives me too much interference (Too weak signal), even in a totally static signal, so I decided to disassemble the transmitter and look for the antenna.
I found that the antenna goes through a bunch of resistors, but why? For what are those? Are they limiting the signal strength, so that it doesn't break laws of some countries, or are those there, because they are needed?

Is there any chance to remove (some) of them and increase the signal, at least a bit?

Below is the image of the "main" transmitter unit:
[image: 20170327_082219.jpg]

And here the image of the bottom unit, which goes to the car's 12V port:
[image: 20170327_083230.jpg]

Any suggestion is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: I only see one resistor to ground, that's probably required for operation. The series part is a capacitor to DC block the antenna port so only the analog part of the signal goes out. It's normal to put a series cap on any antenna input or output ports.

Comment: Your assumption that you can make something cheap "better" just by removing/changing some resistors is wrong. If that were so easy, why didn't the manufacturer do this already ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache, OP has already outlined their reasons in the question, don't need to ask for that information a second time. They were sensible reasons. Read the question properly.

Comment: @Andrew Can I solder a additional antenna at any point on this PCB? Or isn't that possible? And also, thanks for clarifying things :)

Comment: Are those two yellow wires in the pictures connected? It almost looks like the antenna signal goes down the yellow wire into the power socket and is then connected to the cars +12 V rail which it relies on to act as an antenna. Is there some other antenna involved that isn't shown or is that really what's happening? If so then removing the yellow wire from the ANT connection in the first picture and replacing it with a ~95 cm length of wire may work. Make sure you insulate the end of the yellow wire, it'll be at 12 V. If this works then you can remove it completely  but test it first.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the yellow cable is the only antenna and that cable goes down to the 12V socket. If I remove the yellow cable and replace it with an 95 cm cable, it won't have 12V, because it isn't connected to 12V anymore, or is it?

Comment: @Fusseldieb it depends which end you remove ;-) If you remove the power socket end then it won't have 12 volts but you end up with a join in the middle of the antenna and you need to subtract the length of the yellow wire from the 95cm. If you remove the transmitter side then you have a cleaner antenna cable but the yellow wire is at +12V. If you remove the yellow wire completely you have the best of both worlds but more effort to put things back if this doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew Success! I removed the yellow cable from the main unit and attached a 0.30mm ~95cm (green) cable on that solder point and now the reception is much much better... Over 100 meters away and the signal is still acceptable. Thank you for explaining things. If it's okay for you, I'll answer my own question and attach some pictures for future searchers/viewers. :)

Answer (score -2):

Do not know unless you really reverse engineer it. Could be exactly what you say, could be impedance matching, or, in lots of cases, the IC spec sheet required it and the designer put it in without any thought. Regardless, it is a good excuse to take it apart and learn:)

Comment: Your answer is "I don't know", really?